# Indicating a selected item in a listview

Tags: .net, winforms

I have a ListView control in .NET Winforms containing filenames from a directory. When first displaying the control, I populate the listview, then programmatically select the first item in the list thusly:

```
    if (lvwFiles.Items.Count > 0)
    {
        ListViewItem firstItem = lvwFiles.Items[0];
        firstItem.Selected = true;
    }
```

This works fine, except that the first item in the list should be visually highlighted (reverse-highlighted?) to indicate to the user that it's the one selected, as happens if the user then clicks one of the items.

It seems like a dumb question, but I've looked around on Stackoverflow and elsehwere and don't see an obvious answer. Is there an easy way to make this happen via setting a property or something similar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the `HideSelection` property to false in the designer (or through code).  Doing that will allow the selected item to show even when the control does not have focus.

Comment: That was it; thank you! I knew it was something simple/stupid.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this works as I haven't run the program but can't you select the row you want (from lvwFile.Items) and set the Selected value to true. For example:

```
temp.Items(rowIndex).Selected
```

Comment: That's pretty much what I'm doing (if you add " = true" on the end of your line). It does select the item, but it doesn't indicate anything to the user that the row is selected, which is my problem.

Comment: I used devExpress and all I you have to do there is change temp.Items(rowIndex).editValue = true.

Answer (score -1):

Register for the selectedIndexChanged event. Here you can perform whatever visual highlights you need on the selected items.

```
    void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged( object sender, EventArgs e )
    {
        foreach ( ListViewItem lvi in listView1.SelectedItems )
        {
            lvi.BackColor = Color.Black;
            lvi.ForeColor = Color.Chocolate;
        }
        // TODO: Reset the other items to normal.
    }
```

Comment: Why not use the built-in system highlighting?

Comment: This is what I did initially. It works, but it's definitely a suboptimal hack.

Answer (score -1):

What you are doing should work fine.

After a little testing it looks like the listview's tabstop property must be set to true, and the listview has to have a tab index of 0.

Comment: That simply forces the control to have focus when the form is shown.  If the user tabs off the control then the selection will again disappear.

Comment: Correct, since he is talking about having it selected when it's setup (IE: First displaying the control)